# SaveAs MS-Word as docx instead of doc c#

Tags: c#

When i try to save a file with docx extension in winform C# and to open that i get exception:
"word cannot open the file because the file format does not match the file extension"

This is how i save the file:

```
object oMissing = Missing.Value;
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();
oWord.Visible = false;
oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);  

Object oSaveAsFile = (Object)@"C:\test\FINISHED_XML_Template.docx";            
        oWordDoc.SaveAs(ref oSaveAsFile, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        oWordDoc.Close(false, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        oWord.Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Comment: Does the version of the Office COM interop libraries you're using actually support `docx` files?

Comment: I think so, I use Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library

Comment: In `SaveAs` method can you try to specify `Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument` as 2nd parameter value?

Answer (score 0):

This page suggests changing to using the `Word.Application.SaveAs2()` method.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d7a68c0-e2cd-41c0-9815-63f0fde0bc8d/converting-doc-to-docx?forum=worddev

Answer (score 0):

See the answer in this link: [Convert .doc to .docx using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111015/convert-doc-to-docx-using-c-sharp)

Daves solution is like the below, but I have changed Daves code from 
CompatibilityMode:=WdCompatibilityMode.**wdWord2010** to CompatibilityMode:=WdCompatibilityMode.**wdWord2013** to be more up-to-date and to give you true docx (without compability mode).

```
public void ConvertDocToDocx(string path)
{
    Application word = new Application();

    if (path.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc"))
    {
        var sourceFile = new FileInfo(path);
        var document = word.Documents.Open(sourceFile.FullName);

        string newFileName = sourceFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".docx");
        document.SaveAs2(newFileName,WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument, 
                         CompatibilityMode: WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2013);

        word.ActiveDocument.Close();
        word.Quit();

        File.Delete(path);
    }
}
```