# Crystal Report export to .docx format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm trying to export a Crystal Report to .docx format but after a quick search through the web i found some relatively old sites where it was said that Crystal Reports doesn't support .docx but only .doc.

Is this still true?

Best regards,
Rafael Valente

Comment: AFAIK Crystal Reports does not support `docx`, only `doc` to save. You can save a report to doc, and then [convert it to `docx` format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111015/convert-doc-to-docx-using-c-sharp).

Comment: Hi. I will do that. This seems the best solution i have found. Thank you, Rafael Valente.

Comment: There is also a free command line tool called pandoc that can convert your doc to docx -- Not sure why you need docx though... Microsoft Word and LibreOffice should be able to .doc files just fine.

Comment: Hello @Sun, I need to convert from .doc to .docx just for storage purposes. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the old boards are correct, you can't export to docx. To kind of get around this and get a workable view within Word I export as an  HTML file that can be opened in Word then I resave it as docx.

What this does is gives me a better representation of the report as it is in Crystal. If I go doc and save as docx I get some weird anomalies.

I hope this helps. I would have wrote this as a comment however, I don't have enough reputation score to do that yet.

Comment: Hi. I appreciate your response but i have the code built to export to .doc right now so i think that the comment from @RafaelOsipov answers my question. Thank you for your thoughts, though.

Rafael Valente