# Converting Excel (xls, xlsx) file to PDF using ASP.NET Core running on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core

I am not sure if this has been asked before. I have been working on a project that require converting Microsoft Office Documents to PDF using **ASP.NET Core WebAPI** which is running on **Azure App Service** without buying any license for the conversion. With the help of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580718/convert-word-doc-and-docx-format-to-pdf-in-net-core-without-microsoft-office-in), I am done with the doc and docx part.

However, although OpenXMLSDK-PowerTools have some "Excel-related" functions, I am not able to convert Excel files (xls, xlsx) to HTML (Like the discussion mentioned above, I am trying to convert Excel to HTML then to PDF). The below code always complain table not found.

```
SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(path, true);
htmlText = SmlToHtmlConverter.ConvertTableToHtml(document, new SmlToHtmlConverterSettings(), "Sheet1").ToString();
```

```
ArgumentException: Table not found
 Parameter name: tableName
OpenXmlPowerTools.SmlDataRetriever.RetrieveTable(SpreadsheetDocument sDoc, string tableName) in SmlDataRetriever.cs
+
            var styleXDoc = sDoc.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.GetXDocument();
OpenXmlPowerTools.SmlToHtmlConverter.ConvertTableToHtml(SpreadsheetDocument sDoc, SmlToHtmlConverterSettings settings, string tableName) in SmlToHtmlConverter.cs
+
            var rangeXml = SmlDataRetriever.RetrieveTable(sDoc, tableName);
MyProject.Controllers.FileUploadController.ProcessFile(string path, string name, FileType fileType) in FileUploadController.cs
+
                    htmlText = SmlToHtmlConverter.ConvertTableToHtml(document, new SmlToHtmlConverterSettings(), "Sheet1").ToString();
XFStdOfficeDocWebAPI.Controllers.FileUploadController.Index(List<IFormFile> files) in FileUploadController.cs
+
                    FileInfo htmlFileInfo = ProcessFile(filePath, fileName, fileType);
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I am stuck here and not sure what to do next. Any comments / help will be appreciated!