# How To Convert Word To Pdf in .netcore

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf, iis, ms-office

I want to convert word document to pdf in .netcore.
I did that in .net4.5 ,but I need it in .netcore Without installation MicroSoft Office because i host my application on linux.

Comment: You can try using [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)

Comment: You could refer to the answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658645/11398810

Comment: Muhammad hannan Do you have any example to do that

Comment: Rena in your referance i have to install Microsoft Office but i have linux server

Answer (score 0):

You might need to consider using a .NET Standard library that supports conversion to PDF.

One approach that I am familiar with (as I work for the vendor of the toolkit) is the [LEADTOOLS Document Conversion SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/documents/windows/dotnet/winforms/convert-files-with-document-converter.html).

The .NET Core library has a DocumentConverter class that can be used to convert to PDF:

```
using (DocumentConverter documentConverter = new DocumentConverter())
{
   var format = DocumentFormat.Pdf;
   var jobData = DocumentConverterJobs.CreateJobData(inFile, outFile, format);
   jobData.JobName = "conversion job";
   var job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);
   documentConverter.Jobs.RunJob(job);
}
```