# How to convert DOC or DOCX bytes to PDF without using storage [C#]

Tags: c#, file-conversion, export-to-pdf

I have requirement where I have to convert a doc or docx file into PDF. I have the doc file in byte array format. Need to convert that byte array into PDF without using storage. Is there anyway to do that using only memory. Code I use for conversion using storage is as below.

```
string outputFileName = destinationFile;
Interopwrd.Application wordApp = new Interopwrd.Application();
Interopwrd.Document wordDoc = null;
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(sourceFile);
wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(outputFileName, Interopwrd.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
```

I need to do this without saving in in storage. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would just use a [RAM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive), which is block of memory that the OS treats as if it were a disk drive. You can then have Word save to a file on that drive, but it will only exist in memory. That gives you all the performance benefits (and impermanence) of RAM, and the benefits of a file system at the same time. Win-win.

Comment: Nice, add this answer with mine and you have  an **platform neutral Doc/Docx to PDF converter** that works using RAM! https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658645/495455

Comment: Is it possible to use RAM Drive with Interopwrd?

Comment: Sure. The code you have above should work. Just save your file to the RAM drive instead of saving it to a hard drive.