# Converting Docx to PDF using .Net Core [Open Source]

Tags: .net-core

I'm looking for a plugin which can convert word (docx / doc) to pdf Without `Microsoft.Office.Interop` and Open Source one. There are questions asked on it but no solution is provided or I didnt found any.

Any suggestion or references will be much appreciated!.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580718/convert-word-doc-and-docx-format-to-pdf-in-net-core-without-microsoft-office-in

Comment: For a project I did, I just added libreoffice as a dependency, and wrote a function that would let libreoffice do the conversion (This was a PHP project). While not exactly in the spirit of what you are asking, this is a possibility if nothing else turns up, as it is opensource, and you could include the executable in a docker image.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using Aspose.Words project, however this library is not an opensource (license is required and cost some money): https://blog.aspose.com/2020/01/02/convert-word-doc-docx-to-pdf-in-csharp-net-core/

Answer (score -2):

On our project we needed to keep formating as close as the original. But every plugin we tried never came close to the original.

We opted for [I Love Pdf utilities](https://developer.ilovepdf.com/tools).

[Word to PDF](https://developer.ilovepdf.com/docs/guides/office-to-pdf-api)

They have a well documented API for some language (including .Net) and it works great.

You can process 250 files freely every month and if you need more, it's not that expensive.

Hope this helps